# Use While Loop to assign salesperson to customer with Update

Tags: loops, join, for-loop, while-loop

I'd tried to write a statement which can assign salesperson such as `S1, S2, S3` to multiple customers with `WHILE LOOP` but the statement update all customers with the same salesperson ID.

What I'd like to do is to assign 1 salesperson such as `S1, S2, S3` to 1 customer such as `C1, C2,...C9, C10`. The first record is assigned to the customer should not be the salesperson assigned to last customer record assigned. For example, if the latest record in the existing Customer table is

```
  Cust_ID  Cust_Name   Cust_SalesP    Cust_CreatedDate              Cust_UpdatedDate 
  '097'    'John Doe'     'S2'        '2014-01-15 16:59:43.000'     '2015-01-15 16:59:43.000'
```

then the next Salesperson assigned to next Customer should be `S3`. If there are a bulk of customers waiting to be assigned, they should be assigned based on `S1, S2, S3` in sequential order until the last row of record.

The compete scenario based on what I mentioned above would be like this: Customer `098` is assigned to `S3`, `099` is assigned to `S1`, `0100` is assigned to `S2`, `0101` is assigned to `S3`, `0102` is assigned to `S1`, `0103` is assigned to `S2`, and so on...

**Here are the sample tables:**

```
Table A: Customer (Columns include Cust_ID, Cust_Name, Cust_SalesP, Cust_CreatedDate, Cust_UpdatedDate)
Table B: Salesperson (Columns include SalesP_ID, SalesP_CreatedDate, SalesP_UpdatedDate)
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?  Can you show the attempt you made to provide a little more context?

Comment: It's T-SQL. Here us what I tried to do:<p>DECLARE CustAssignment_cursor CURSOR FOR

select * from Customer order by Cust_UpdatedDate desc
OPEN CustAssignment_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM CustAssignment_cursor;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
   Update Customer
   Set Cust_SalesP = (Case
     When Cust_Id = 'S1' then 'S2'
     When Cust_Id = 'S2' then 'S3' 
     When Cust_Id = 'S3' then 'S1' 
     end)   
      FETCH NEXT FROM CustAssignment_cursor;
   END;

CLOSE CustAssignment_cursor;
DEALLOCATE CustAssignment_cursor;
GO

Answer (score 0):

> "...but the statement update all customers with the same salesperson ID..."

Most likely, you are writing an `Update` Statement without the `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a purely SQL based solution, it would be possible just by declaring an int variable to represent your salesperson and adding 1 to it each time through the loop. To reset it you would just use an If...Else to check the current number and reset it to 1 before the next iteration of the loop.

Something like this, maybe:

```
DECLARE @cust_id INT
DECLARE @sales_number INT
SET @sales_number = 1

DECLARE C1 CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT [Cust_ID]
FROM Customers
WHERE Cust_SalesP IS NULL

OPEN C1

FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO 

@cust_id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
exec sp_executesql 'UPDATE Customers set Cust_SalesP =''S'+sales_number + '''
           WHERE Cust_ID = '+@cust_id      

IF @sales_number = 3 
    SET @sales_number = 1
ELSE
    SET @sales_number = @sales_number + 1

FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO 

  @cust_id

END

CLOSE C1

DEALLOCATE C1
```